# Invariant in-center of triangles with one vertex fixed

Tags: trigonometry

Find all coordinates (loci) of two triangle vertices $A(-p,q), B(r,s)$ along with the third fixed point $C(0,-1)$ that makes the origin $ O(0,0) $ as in-center of $ABC$.

Comment: I think its just too many variables. Is there any relation between A,B ?

Comment: No, trying to imagine patches for $A,B$

Comment: Do you mean the centre of gravity? In this case, point D(0, 1/2) is the middle of opposite side (given that  the medians divided in relation 2:1), so a pair of points A and B will be equidistant from D and form a straight line with D. Don't think, it will be a particular locus, since the distance can vary.

Comment: Unless you introduce parameters $u$ and $v$ (both non-zero), so (assuming A(p,q), not A(-p,q)) $p=\frac{1}{2}+u$, $q=v$, $r=\frac{1}{2}-u$, $s=−v$

Comment: It is the in-center, not center of gravity.